# What is the maximum number of features a SDE featureclass can hold?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase

I have a SDE 10.0 Geodatabase based on MS SQL 2008.

I'm running a continuous process where about 6400 point features are written to a feature-class every hour.  I need it to be a featureclass, since I'm doing some krigging on the feature-class, after applying an attribute query based on a time field in the data.

I was wondering what is the limitation on the number of features a SDE Feature-class can hold?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ArcGIS fails to import all records from huge CSV file to file geodatabase table despite being within FGDB table size limits](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33039/arcgis-fails-to-import-all-records-from-huge-csv-file-to-file-geodatabase-table)

Comment: @radouxju This is not a duplicate as that question talks about File Geodatabse, and none of the answers talk about max number of features in a SDE Featureclass

Comment: @ devadatta : my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two billion features, plus or minus (2^31-2 legal rowid values). I've only loaded 80m personally, but a colleague used my tools to load 680m in Oracle, SQL-Server, and PostgreSQL servers, side by side. That said, the effective useful limit is a lot closer to 20-50 million features.

Tables loaded over time are extremely vulnerable to the effects of spatial fragmentation, which will destroy spatial-first query performance in tables over 2 million rows.  If you plan to let the table grow unbounded, you'll need to implement a mitigation plan.

There are an infinite number of permutations of database product, geometry storage, versioning status, and insert behavior which could limit row count -- 2^31-7 versioned edits of an SDEBINARY layer would limit the business table to 5 rows.

For your use case of simple feature insert, the limit is "two gigafeatures". Once you start moving features, then you run into a different limit -- "the total number of features a layer has ever held since the last TRUNCATE" (which is also two gigafeatures). This is probably why "the limit" is not documented.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a source citation for the number? We are in the process of periodically moving to different tables, but we are debating whether we should do it  monthly, bimonthly, or quarterly.

Comment: You need a source for the maximum value of a signed 32-bit integer?

Comment: I need a source that 32 bit integer limit for the ObjectId is the limiting factor, and not something else.

Comment: As an clarification to my last comment, imagine this situation. Supposed it is a Versioned fc. Maybe the A & D tables have some effect on the limitation. (I don't know if it's true, just an example of what could be a limiting factor)

Comment: There are an infinite number of permutations of database product, geometry storage, versioning status, and insert behavior which could limit row count -- 2^31-7 versioned edits of an SDEBINARY layer would limit the business table to 5 rows.  For your use case of simple feature insert, the limit is "two gigafeatures".  Once you start moving features, then you run into a *different* limit -- "the total number of features a layer has ever held since the last TRUNCATE" (which is also two gigafeatures).  This is probably why "the limit" is not documented.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 10.1 the new 64 bit version will allow you to store and index up to 2^64 records theoratically. That's alot.

Of course you have to enable geodatabase archiving if you are aiming this high.