# ArcMap fails to convert all records from CSV file using Table to Table geoprocessing tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, csv, file-geodatabase, large-datasets

I am using the table to table geoprocessing tool to convert a CSV file with nearly 5 million records into an GDB table in a file geodatabase. The tool succeeds each time, but only 603 records are converted in the output file. ArcMap provides no error message, yet only converts a fraction of the original data. The record in the break-off point shows no particular oddities.
I am running ArcGIS 10.5.1

Comment: I had this problem years ago: [ArcGIS fails to import all records from huge CSV file to file geodatabase table despite being within FGDB table size limits](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33039/arcgis-fails-to-import-all-records-from-huge-csv-file-to-file-geodatabase-table). Do you have the 64-bit geoprocessing addon?

Comment: Thank you, I just checked got it through someone in the office. I'll check and see if it fixes my issue.

Comment: I attempted the geoprocessing tool with the 64-bit add-on, yet the tool still only produces 603 records each time

Comment: I think the suggested duplicate may still help you, particularly [the answer that discusses an InsertCursor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/40785/15768). If nothing else, the row-by-row cursor approach is more likely to give you a verbose complaint if it's encountering a problem with the specific data in row # 604.